# Is there a way in Loopback 4 with MongoDB to reference a document in an array of ids (like "populate" in mongoose)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopback4

I am recently studying Loopback 4 and I would like to know if there is a way similar to the populate of mongoose to achieve this:

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectId('xxx'),
  name: 'First',
  elements: [
    ObjectId('xxx'),
    ObjectId('xxx'),
    ObjectId('xxx')
  ]
}
```

I would like to become

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectId('xxx'),
  name: 'First',
  elements: [
    {_id: ObjectId('xxx'), name: 'Sub1'}
    {_id: ObjectId('xxx'), name: 'Sub2'}
    {_id: ObjectId('xxx'), name: 'Sub3'}
  ]
}
```

**In the sub documents there is no foreign key, so (I think) I cannot use the relations hasMany, hasOne etc etc**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would `$lookup` do what you need?

Comment: Yes I tried but unfortunately the installed version of mongo doesn't support the $lookup `(MongoError: exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup')` and it is not currently possible to update mongo